# Command for Weekly agenda view in org mode

Tags: emacs

In org mode, C-c C-a does not show the weekly agenda.

Tried the following

https://orgmode.org/worg/orgcard.html - shows the keybinding is C-c a a. That doesn't work.

Tried to find the command for compiling the weekly agenda by searching inside the buffer showing the `describe-mode`. Tried using keywords agenda, compil, week.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Agenda-commands.html

The command mentioned here - `org-agenda-week-view` is not recognized by emacs 26.x

What is the command called and how do I find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The command is `org-agenda`. the keybindings need to be changed to global-keys.

Now it works.

Comment: It is described in the introduction of the org manual, in the "Activation" section: https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation